# TYPO3 composer installation localy on ddev - The requested resource "" was not found

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-9.x, ddev

i have ddev running locally on my windows machine.
I worked all the time on my TYPO3 installation, it was working fine and the only thing i did yesterday was to patch it from 9.5.18 to 9.5.19. Even after that, it worked fine.

As i wanted to start today, i get the message

> The requested resource "" was not found

, when I want to get to the backend (/typo3). The installtool is working but has no styling at all.
The Front End is working fine.

[here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIYxy.png)

Any idea where i can could take a look at? I already restarted my machine, ddev, docker and went back to an older composer.lock, `composer dumpautoload` and cleared typo3temp but nothing worked.

Comment: I had this on a previous update a few weeks ago on 1 installation while I was updating a few dozen. What fixed it was deleting typo3conf/PackageStates.php. I did have to turn on all the extensions again after that of course, but it still worked after I'd done that. As this was only in 1 installation and the others were fine I didn't investigate it further so I don't know what caused it or if there's a better solution. Not a real answer, but perhaps it will help you.

Comment: @RudyGnodde That actually solved my problem. Thank you **alot**. If you want, you can put this as an answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Yesterday Packagist, where lots of composer packages come from, was working really, really badly. All tests that rely on composer were failing. I think this is also a likely culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this on a previous update a few weeks ago on 1 installation while I was updating a few dozen. What fixed it was deleting typo3conf/PackageStates.php. I did have to turn on all the extensions again after that of course, but it still worked after I'd done that. As this was only in 1 installation and the others were fine I didn't investigate it further so I don't know what caused it or if there's a better solution. Not a real answer, but perhaps it will help you.